# Google my business Category list API Error

Tags: android, google-my-business-api

I want to get list of category from google my business category list API https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/categories/list

Couldn't found much details on official sites

I tried with many account but getting this error
"message":"Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute"

"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"

"reason": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",

Does any body has parsed this API before?

Answer (score 0):

Since the categories.list method belonging to v4 of the GMB API is deprecated and will be removed soon, I would first suggest using
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/categories/list
instead.

To check your quotas, visit

- [Old API quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/quotas)
- [New API quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/quotas)

Your general request quota will probably be 300 or 600 requests per minute.
In order not to hit quota issues, you should implement a rate limiting strategy on your end. For further reading, see https://cloud.google.com/architecture/rate-limiting-strategies-techniques

Comment: Have you ever managed to get this working? The api worked fine prior to 2022, but after the change i am getting constant rate limit exceeded messages and google did not seem to answer to any of requests.

Comment: As I tried to explain, v4 is deprecated, the new API works just fine if you have quota.

Comment: yes, i have tried migrating from v4 to the new api, but it is simply impossible to get quota request response for me, no response whatsoever. and when i try to perform **anything** on the new api without quota increased - i get quota exceeded error message, even after a single action